# All Day Events not correct in Rest Service/iNotes Calendar Control

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

All Day Events are displayed incorrectly in an iNotes Calendar Control:
only the 1st day of a multiday event (e.g. holiday) is displayed,
plus days following another calendar entries.

e.g. All Day Event from Jan 20th to Jan 27th
is only displayed on Jan 20th
when I add an appointment (or meeting) to the calendar, e.g. on the 22th:
Then the All Day Event is displayed on Jan 20th and Jan 23rd (or 22nd, sometimes).

--- crazy ---
and now "nobody" (in my company) is trusting the calendar control any longer!

the code:

```
<xe:restService id="restCal" pathInfo="/calendar"
preventDojoStore="false">
<xe:this.service>
<xe:calendarJsonLegacyService
viewName="$calendar" colAltSubject="$151" colCalendarDate="$134"
colChair="$153" colConfidential="$154" colCustomData="$UserData"
colEndTime="$146" colEntryIcon="$149" colEntryType="$152"
colStartTime="$144" colStatus="$160" colSubject="$147"
contentType="text/json" databaseName="${javascript:sessionScope.calendarDBName}">
</xe:calendarJsonLegacyService>
</xe:this.service>
</xe:restService>

<xe:calendarView id="calendarAD"
storeComponentId="restCal"
type="#{javascript: null == viewScope.calendarType? 'W' : viewScope.calendarType }">
</xe:calendarView>
```

edited (after Paul's comment):
The firebug data shows that the all day event is written 3 times with the same date/time values, until a different appointment data is written:

```
      "@unid":"B4E518662A79F897C1257B160067B553",
      "@noteid":"147E6",
      "@position":"632",
      "@siblings":"641",
      "entrydata":
      [
        {
            "@columnnumber":"0",
            "@name":"$134",
            "datetimelist":
            {
                "datetime":
                [
                  {
                      "0":"20130219T040000"
                  }
                ]
            }
        }, 
// ========================================
// ... some more code 
// ... than again the all day event with the SAME date/time value :
// ========================================
      "@unid":"B4E518662A79F897C1257B160067B553",
      "@noteid":"147E6",
      "@position":"632",
      "@siblings":"641",
      "entrydata":
      [
        {
            "@columnnumber":"0",
            "@name":"$134",
            "datetimelist":
            {
                "datetime":
                [
                  {
                      "0":"20130219T040000"
                  }
                ]
            }
        }, 
// ========================================
// ... some more code 
// ... and a 3rd time, with the SAME date/time value:
// ========================================
      "@unid":"B4E518662A79F897C1257B160067B553",
      "@noteid":"147E6",
      "@position":"632",
      "@siblings":"641",
      "entrydata":
      [
        {
            "@columnnumber":"0",
            "@name":"$134",
            "datetimelist":
            {
                "datetime":
                [
                  {
                      "0":"20130219T040000"
                  }
                ]
            }
        }, 
// ========================================
// .... some more code 
// ... then followed by a different appointment:
// ========================================
      "@unid":"ADA38EEBCC643595C1257B160068056A",
      "@noteid":"147EA",
      "@position":"635",
      "@siblings":"641",
      "entrydata":
      [
        {
            "@columnnumber":"0",
            "@name":"$134",
            "datetime":
            {
                "0":"20130221T090000"
            }
        }, 
// ========================================
//... some more code 
//... AND THEN the all day event again, now with a changed date value:
// ========================================
      "@unid":"B4E518662A79F897C1257B160067B553",
      "@noteid":"147E6",
      "@position":"634",
      "@siblings":"641",
      "entrydata":
      [
        {
            "@columnnumber":"0",
            "@name":"$134",
            "datetimelist":
            {
                "datetime":
                [
                  {
                      "0":"20130221T040000"
                  }
                ]
            }
        },
```

Any solution would be greatly appreciated

Uwe

Comment: What does the JSON data show, for this and for other multi-day calendar event types?

Comment: Hi Paul - I'm not sure if this (firebug) is the data you asked for? It begins like: 
{
    "@timestamp":"20130219T101528",
    "@toplevelentries":"641",
    "viewentry":
    [
      {
          "@unid":"B4E518662A79F897C1257B160067B553",
          "@noteid":"147E6",
          "@position":"632",
          "@siblings":"641",
          "entrydata":
          [
            {
                "@columnnumber":"0",
                "@name":"$134",
                "datetimelist":
                {
                    "datetime":

Comment: Yes, that JSON is the source data for the calendar control. It sounds like the all day event's data is passed differently to other multi-day events (if those other events show correctly). If the JSON is different, the problem is likely to be in the content on the underlying view or the REST service's retrieval of the data rather than the calendar control itself.

Comment: I posted the data into my question - and hope it's understandable. Looks as if the all day events are somehow "stacked": 3 entries with the same date/time values, then the different appointment, then again stacked all-day-event entries.